# Class to represent a Range of percentage values

Tags: c++

I've developed a class which is designed to hold a range of percentage values. The following is the intended functionality:

1. The range should store two bounds (a lower and an upper)
2. The bounds should be percentages expressed as a double decimal and should be >= 0 and <=1
3. Each bound could be inclusive or exclusive
4. The lower bound should not be greater or equal than the lower
5. The range class should have a method to tell whether a given double decimal is within the range.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// we are comparing doubles so we cannot rely on ==
bool cmpd (double num1, double num2)
{
    const double epsilon = 0.000001;
    if (std::abs(num1 - num2) <= epsilon) {
      return true;
    }
    return std::abs(num1 - num2) <= epsilon * std::max(std::abs(num1), std::abs(num2));
}

enum class BoundType
{
    Inclusive,
    Exclusive
};

struct Bound
{
   private:
        double mBoundPerc;
        BoundType mBoundType;
        
   public:
        Bound() = default;
        
        Bound(double perc, BoundType bType)
        {
            // If bound is not greater than or equal to 0 then invalid
            if (!(perc > 0) && !cmpd(perc, 0) )
            {
                throw "Invalid range";
            }
            
            // If bound is not lower than or equal to 1 then invalid
            if (!(perc < 1) && !cmpd(perc,1))
            {
                throw "Invalid range";
            }
            
            mBoundPerc = perc, mBoundType = bType;
        }

        double getBound() 
        {
            return mBoundPerc;
        }
        
        BoundType getBoundType()
        {
            return mBoundType;
        }
};


class PercRange 
{
    private:
        Bound mLowerBound, mUpperBound;
        
        bool isRangeValid(Bound lower, Bound upper) {
            
            // a range is invalid if lower >= upper
            if (lower.getBound() > upper.getBound() || cmpd(lower.getBound(), upper.getBound()) )
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    
    public:
        PercRange(Bound lower, Bound upper)
        {
            if (!setRange(lower, upper ))
            {
                throw "Range invalid";
            }
        }
        
        bool setRange(Bound lower, Bound upper )
        {
            if (!isRangeValid(lower, upper))
            {
                return false;
            }
            mLowerBound = lower, mUpperBound = upper;
            return true;
        }
        
        
        bool isWithin(double num)
        {
            // if lower boud is inclusive then num must either be equal to or greater than lower bound 
            if (mLowerBound.getBoundType() == BoundType::Inclusive && !(cmpd(num, mLowerBound.getBound()) || num > mLowerBound.getBound() ) )
            {
                return false;
            }
            
            // if lower bound exclusive then num must be greater than lower bound
            if (mLowerBound.getBoundType() == BoundType::Exclusive && !(num > mLowerBound.getBound()))
            {
                return false;
            }
            
            // if upper boud is inclusive then num must either be equal to or less than upper bound 
            if (mUpperBound.getBoundType() == BoundType::Inclusive && !(cmpd(num, mUpperBound.getBound()) || num < mUpperBound.getBound()))
            {
                return false;
            }
            
            // if upper bound exclusive then num must be less than upper bound
            if (mUpperBound.getBoundType() == BoundType::Exclusive && !(num < mUpperBound.getBound())) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
};


int main()
{
   PercRange range(Bound(0.2, BoundType::Inclusive), Bound(0.4, BoundType::Exclusive) );
   
   cout << range.isWithin(0.2) << endl;  // 1
   cout << range.isWithin(0.199) << endl;  // 0
   
   cout << range.isWithin(0.399) << endl;  // 1
   cout << range.isWithin(0.4) << endl;  // 0
   
   Bound bound (1, BoundType::Inclusive);


   return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid floating point math if you need it to be exact

Let's look at this code:

```
const double epsilon = 0.000001;
if (std::abs(num1 - num2) <= epsilon) {
    return true;
}
```

Why did you pick that value of epsilon? Is it really precise enough? What if I do the following:

```
const double epsilon = 0.000001;
PercRange range(Bound(0.2, BoundType::Inclusive), Bound(0.4, BoundType::Exclusive));

std::cout << range.isWithin(0.2 - epsilon / 2.0) << '\n';
```

Clearly the value I'm testing is outside the range, but it's returning `1` anyway. That is not what you would expect.

If you want to deal with values with two decimals, then use an integer type to store the values pre-multiplied by 100. This way you can use exact integer math and you will always exactly get what you want. However, that only works if you use those integers everywhere. As soon as you are converting to or from floating points, you have to deal with possible rounding errors.

I you don't want to go this route, then just accept the way [IEEE 754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) works, and don't try to introduce epsilons.

## Simplify your code

You are introducing two classes and and enum, just for checking if a value is between two other values. Is this really necessary? I would create single function that can check if a value is within the range of another:

```
bool isBetween(double value, double low, double high) {
    return value >= low && value < high;
}
```

You could consider adding an `assert(low <= high)` statement to that function to get error checking. And then if I want to compare things often against the same range, I can write:

```
int main() {
    auto isInRange = [](double value){ return isBetween(value, 0.2, 0.4); };

    std::cout << isInRange(0.2) << '\n';
    std::cout << isInRange(0.199) << '\n';
    std::cout << isInRange(0.399) << '\n';
    std::cout << isInRange(0.4) << '\n';
}
```